# Transparently edit remote files on Windows, with ssh/Putty and netrw

Tags: vim

Ok guys, maybe this one has been asked before, but I searched and ran threw nothing, so i'm taking a chance here.

I'm using the latest vim (gvim 7.3), on Windows 7 64bits.

I've got some remote files that I want to edit directly with vim, using netrw.

Right now, I've got a fully working transparent ssh connexion to my remote hosts, thanks to Putty, Pageant and public/private keys.

I've successfully setup a read/write access to distant files with those fixes:

```
#### .vimrc ####
let g:netrw_cygwin= 0
let g:netrw_scp_cmd = 'c:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\pscp.exe -q -batch'
let g:netrw_sftp_cmd= '"c:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\psftp.exe'
```

Then I can access a file with :

```
:e scp:\\user@host:port\\home\me\some-file.txt
```

And, each time I access remote file, Vim run a windows prompt (cmd.exe) :

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\pscp.exe -q -batch
 -P 22 "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\VIF215E.tmp" "user@host:/home/me/some-file.txt"
Hit any key to close this window...
```

My problem is that hitting a key outside Vim each time I want to open/write a file isn't efficient at all.

So my question(s) is(are) :

- Am I doing it the right way ?
- Is there another way of transparently
  accessing a remote file with ssh on
  Windows ?
- If no, is there a way to
  get rid of "Hit any key to close this
  window..." when Vim launches putty's pscp.exe ?

Thanks a lot and happy vimming.

**EDIT:** Note to the *myself* in the past: *Dude, just go with linux and vanilla gvim/ssh. You'll thank me later (and take a look at spf13-vim)*

Comment: I take it Samba isn't an option?

Comment: Well, it could be an option, but I want to edit files on a live web server (I know, do-not-ever-edit-on-a-live-environment...). So the less I charge it the better. Ssh sounded like a clean solution, but I'm starting to wonder... For now I'm stuck with a netbeans 6.9 "remote/sftp" project, which is working great, but it will never as quick and fun as a great implementation of vim/ssh could be. Maybe I *should* start thinking about replacing Win7 by a fresh Debian...

Comment: Assuming the server has Vim, why don't you edit the files directly on the server? It would be a **lot** faster.

Answer (score 5):

These are what I got working today (gVim 7.3 in Win 7) (took me many hours to finally get something working):

```
set nocompatible
let g:netrw_cygwin = 0
let g:netrw_list_cmd = "plink.exe -P ##### -pw MyPass user@host.com ls -Fa "
let g:netrw_ssh_cmd  = "plink -T -ssh"
let g:netrw_scp_cmd  = "pscp -P ##### -pw MyPass -scp"
let g:netrw_sftp_cmd = "pscp -pw MyPass -sftp"
or
let g:netrw_sftp_cmd = "psftp -P ##### -pw MyPass user@host.com"
```

With the first command make sure there's a [space] after -Fa or you'll get errors.
Then you can connect in Vim via

```
:e scp://user@host:port#/(path to file)
:e sftp://user@host:port#/(path to file)
```

I hope this helps some Vimmers struggling to figure this out and get it working.
Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Just put this line in your vimrc:

```
let g:netrw_silent = 1
```

This will run scp asynchronously (like using !start)

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit too elaborate.

I use SSHFS on Linux to accomplish this. It allows you to locally mount a remote path over SSH.

Something similar is available for Windows now as well: http://dokan-dev.net/en/. It should remove the need for all the modifications on the Vim side.

Comment: Thank You, I'v been looking for something like this a long time ago!

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great!

Unfortunately, DokanSSHFS.exe doesn't work on Windows 7 64bits (it crashes right after its start)...

Comment: For the record, quoted from the dokan page : "Dokan library supports 64 bit operating system. However, user-mode library runs as 32 bit application and Dokan.NET library is a 32 bit library. You have to configure your .NET application to run on x86 platform."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
let g:netrw_scp_cmd = 'c:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\pscp.exe -q -batch'
```

I had to use

```
let g:netrw_scp_cmd = 'c:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\pscp.exe -q'
```

In windows 7, putty version 0.6, -batch option was not working!

Comment: What's weird is that I get a C:\program can't be found with with "c:\program files (x86)\Putty\pscp.exe" and not c:\"program files (x86)"\putty\pscp.exe. +1 for the position of the quotes (also removed -batch) but don't know if that made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

[WINSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is awesome.  I think it copies a temp file locally then FTPs it but it is "transparent" and is very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's a lot easier to just run cygwin. Install openssh and gvim in cygwin, then run:

```
$ gvim scp://user@host//path/to/file
```

Note the double slashes between the host and the path. Without the extra slash, it'll read the path as relative to the user's home directory.